# Matrix in python with a set column

Tags: python, list, matrix

So I'm trying to make a 2x3 matrix with the output

```
    >>>l([1980, 1981, 1982])
    >>>[[1., 1980], [1., 1981], [1.,1982]]
```

However the output I'm getting is:

```
    >>>l([1980, 1981, 1982])
    >>>[1.0, [1980, 1981, 1982]]
```

my code is:

```
def l(x):   
    for i in range(len(x)):
        xl  = [1., x]
    return xl
```

I know I have to reiterate it multiple times using a for loop, but I'm not entirely sure how to do it.

Comment: Why do you have a loop if it assigns *exactly* the same thing to `xl` each iteration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a nice way to do it with a list comprehension:

```
def l(x):  
    return [[1., e] for e in x]
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is

```
def l(x):  
    xl = [] 
    for i in range(len(x)):
        xl.append([1., x[i]])
    return xl
```

Or, since there is no need to use the index `i` for anything other than indexing the elements of `x`, you can use:

```
def l(x):  
    xl = [] 
    for e in x:
        xl.append([1., e])
    return xl
```

Or you can simply compress all of this into a list concatenation as in Tim's answer:

```
def l(x):
    return [[1., e] for e in x]
```

Comment: While this is useful since it most closely parallels the OP's solution, I really think it's worth emphasizing that `range(len(x))` is usually an antipattern in Python

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` also:

```
>>> li=[1980, 1981, 1982]
>>> map(lambda e: [1.0]+[e], li)
[[1.0, 1980], [1.0, 1981], [1.0, 1982]]
```

Or, if you don't mind a list of tuples:

```
>>> zip((1.0,)*len(li),li)
[(1.0, 1980), (1.0, 1981), (1.0, 1982)]
```

Or, if you want to fix yours:

```
>>> li2=[]
>>> for e in li:
...    li2.append([1.0,e])
... 
>>> li2
[[1.0, 1980], [1.0, 1981], [1.0, 1982]]
```